# How to resolve drawing a circle button with an icon at the center error in Android?

Tags: android, button, geometry, icons

I am using a Button that belongs to this namespace `com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton`, I want to draw a circular Button with the picture of a `microphone` at the center with the following markup..

```
 <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.Icon"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        app:icon="@drawable/mic"
        app:iconSize="24dp"
        app:iconPadding="0dp"
        android:insetLeft="0dp"
        android:insetTop="0dp"
        android:insetRight="0dp"
        android:insetBottom="0dp"
       app:shapeAppearanceOverlay="@style/ShapeAppearanceOverlay.MyApp.Button.Rounded"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

The markup in my style that was referenced in that Button above is here below

```
  <style name="ShapeAppearanceOverlay.MyApp.Button.Rounded" parent="">
    <item name="cornerFamily">rounded</item>
    <item name="cornerSize">50%</item>
  </style>
```

I am getting an error that `attr/cornerFamily` and `attr/cornerSize` are not defined from the `styles.xml file`, please help me resolve this, Thank You.

Comment: Which version of the material library do you use?

Comment: @maryam, lemme check , getting back to you in a few

Comment: `Xamarin.Google.Android.Material 1.0.0.1`

Comment: Oh. I'm a native android developer (write java/kotlin code). And the version that I used is `com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0`. You may need to upgrade material version.

Comment: Okay but its the same library, the Xamarin namespace is just a managing tool, I suppose on your end it should e equal to `1.0.1`